# How to specify Win32 as output when invoking GCC using MinGW on Windows

Tags: c, windows, gcc, assembly, mingw

> How to specify Win32 as output when invoking GCC using MinGW on Windows.

Below I've posted my source code. My objective is to interface assembly with C code and produce an executable.

I start assembling the add.asm to Win32 using the following NASM command:

```
nasm -f win32 add.asm
```

Then it should be possible to invoke GCC using both C and object files?

```
gcc -o add add.obj call_asm.c
```

However, this results in an a linkage error:

```
C:\Users\nze\AppData\Local\Temp\cckUvRyC.o:call_asm.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `add'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I instead compile to ELF using

```
nasm -f elf add.asm
```

the command (this time using the ELF file add.o)

```
gcc -o add add.o call_asm.c
```

works perfectly.

**How can I tell GCC that my object files are in Win32 format, so that it should compile call_asm.c to Win32 before linking? (I guess this is the core of the problem, please comment whether I'm correct).**

call_add.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int add(int a, int b);

int main()
{
  printf("%d", add(7, 6));
}
```

add.asm:

```
    BITS 32
    global _add

_add:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, [ebp+8]
    mov ebx, [ebp+12]
    add eax, ebx

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Comment: I don't see the problem with this, it looks like you do the same thing as examples here (for example :) ): https://www.hackthissite.org/articles/read/1079 ... (except you do the "_" prefix thing in the source, not on command line, and you compile+link the .c in the same step, but neither of those should be a problem). Maybe try to split compilation/linking, and check objdump the .o files if the symbols are as expected? (or maybe somebody else can spot the problem here :) )

Comment: Could it be GCC producing an ELF object file before trying to link with the (Windows) PE object file?

Comment: Are you sure you have mingw gcc, rather than a cross-compiler?  I mean, maybe you installed a gcc that runs on Windows but compiles for Linux.  That is something some people would want, so I'm not surprised it exists; it's just not what *you* want.  Run `gcc -v` to see how your gcc is configured.

Comment: I will do that, but why does GCC produce an exe from ELF's that runs on Windows?

Comment: Shouldn't `nasm -f win32 add.asm` produce an `add.obj` rather than an `add.o`?

Comment: It does. The first invocation of GCC is using this .obj file. The next invocation that works use the .o file.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I get this info from gcc -v: 
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC)

Comment: Update your question with the full `gcc -v` output.  It's much more than just one line.  The `Target: x86_64-linux-gnu` or whatever part is highly relevant.  Also: does `gcc -m32` help?  `-m64` is the normal default for gcc on Linux.  I would have thought you'd get error messages about incompatible object files instead of just a symbol not found, though.  Also, do you have the Cygwin or mingw `file` command?  Or `nm` or `objdump`?  Make sure the name-mangling is happening the way you expect, and that your compiled C output does have an unresolved `_add` symbol, not some other mangling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't what you assume it is.  GCC is generating "win32" format (more commonly know as PECOFF) object files. The problem is that your assembly code doesn't define a section, and this results in NASM not defining the symbol `_add` in the generated object file.

If you add a SECTION directive your code links and runs without error:

```
    BITS 32

    SECTION .text
    global _add

_add:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, [ebp+8]
    mov ebx, [ebp+12]
    add eax, ebx

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Telling NASM to generate and ELF object file changes its behaviour, for whatever reason, and causes it to define the `_add` symbol in the ELF object file.

Comment: Thank you! Should the global symbols always be inside a section or can they stand outside as long as the .text section is defined?

Comment: @Nicolas - The `text` section is supposed to contain the executable code. Because someone's grandfather decided that. The ELF format was designed by someone-else's grandfather, so it has slightly different rules. "Because".

Answer (score 0):

Just add this before the label:

```
.globl  _add
```

To get that symbol to export in a .DLL you should add this at the end of the file:

```
.section .drectve
.ascii " -export:\"add\""
```

Note that the leading underscore is left out.